# How to select subcategory in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I can get main categories with this query:

```
DataTable dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES");
```

But I want to get subcategories so I'm trying this query:

```
DataTable dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID="+CategoryID);
```

But I got error with this.. pls help.

> Incorrect syntax near '='. (Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where
>   SubCategoryID = ) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Incorrect syntax near '='.
>   (Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID = )

[image: categories table is here]

```
private void BindRepeater()
{
    DataTable dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID="+CategoryID);
    if (dtCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rpCategory.DataSource = dtCategory;
        rpCategory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the error occurs because your `SubCategoryID` is `null`

Comment: What is the type of `SubCategoryID` column? What `system.GetDataTable` method do exactly? BTW, your `WHERE` parts are different in your two code example.

Comment: I bet `CategoryID` is null in your code. Is it right?

Comment: are  you passing CategoryID as null in string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `CategoryID` is null before building the query:

```
DataTable dtCategory;

if (CategoryID != null)    
    dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID="+CategoryID);
else
    dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let us know what is the type of CategoryID? If it is a string, then the check would be something like this;

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CategoryID))
  dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID IS NULL");
else
  dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID="+CategoryID);
```

If this doesn't help then please provide us more information on CategoryID to help you resolve this error.

Comment: CategoryID int PrimaryKey, SubCategoryID int

Comment: Can you please let us know the type of the variable CategoryID that is declared and defined in C#? By how the CategoryID is used to form the query, I understand that is of a string type.

Comment: its working with this  `if (SubCategoryID == null)` but  after deleting i lost data then i rebind data but it doesn work i dont know why?

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
this.BindRepeater();
}

Comment: if (Process == "Delete")
        {....   finally {   cnn.Close();   DeleteMsg.Visible = true;    }     }
          
                this.BindRepeater();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your system.GetDataTable method does.
Try this.

```
           DataTable dtCategory = new DataTable();

            int CategoryID = 0;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string query = "Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID = " + CategoryID;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                a.Fill(dtCategory);
            }

            foreach (var subCategories  in dtCategory.Rows)
            {

                   // your logic goes here

            }
```